# REST call throwing java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, linux, rest, weblogic, firewall

I am making a REST web service call through firewall with the following code:

```
try {
    String url="http://testcall.us:1300/abc/testapi/json/method1"; //dummy url
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);

    ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .header("content-type", "application/json")
        .get(ClientResponse.class);                         

    System.out.println("response.getStatus" + response.getStatus());
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Error making webservice call", e);
}
```

The code works perfectly fine from my local windows environment. But when I make the same request from another linux server, I get the following exception:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.io.EOFException: Response had end of stream after 0 bytes
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
.......
.......

Caused By: java.io.EOFException: Response had end of stream after 0 bytes
at weblogic.net.http.MessageHeader.isHTTP(MessageHeader.java:312)
at weblogic.net.http.MessageHeader.parseHeader(MessageHeader.java:232)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:554)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:688)
......
......
```

When I make another POST request from the same url (with a different method),

```
try {
    String url="http://testcall.us:1300/abc/testapi/json/method2"; //dummy url
    Client client = Client.create();

    WebResource webResource = client
            .resource(url);                    

    String input = "{\"Id\":" + String.valueOf(id) + ",\"Status\":" + null + "}";

    ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
            .header("Environment", "dev")
            .accept("application/json")
            .post(ClientResponse.class, input);

    if (response.getStatus() != 200 && response.getStatus() != 201) {
        logger.error("REST ws call failed. HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
    }

    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println(output);

} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Error submitting request", e );
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
<Error submitting request
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570)
.....
.....
Caused By: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.readv0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.readv(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:278)
```

This method again works perfectly fine from my local environment. What could be the reason for the same url throwing an exception while it works fine in another environment? As per my knowledge, firewall rules have been approved for the Linux environment. 
Thanks in advance for any insight.

**UPDATE**
I just found out that the firewall rule submitted for this url contained an 'https' instead of 'http'. But as far as I know, firewall doesn't care if it is a 'http' or 'https'. I dont have access to the Linux machine, so cant check if we can get a response using the url there :( .

**UPDATE**
Using 'curl' command on putty, I am able to get a response on the linux server. Does it mean there is something missing with java/weblogic configurations??